# Replace MySQL values in over 120 tables

Tags: mysql, regex, replace, vbulletin

We have redirect huge internet service from domain .de to domain .com - this is discussion board (vBulletin). At the moment we need to change all phrases like "domainame.de" to "domainame.com":

- Over 120 tables (posts, threads)
- A lot of MySQL fields

Anyone have suggestion how do something like this? We need replace string "domainame.de" to "domainname.com" - everywhere.

Comment: Write a script to do it? You'll need to loop through every table, row, and column. You should, of course, try this on a copy to ensure it runs OK before doing it on live data. You'll need to make a decision, depending on how long it takes to run, whether it is acceptable to run such a script on your live database (as you'll have a mix of domains while the script is running), or whether you'll need to have downtime. I'd use PHP or similar scripting language for this, btw.

Comment: @halfer: wait, are you saying there's no special SQL command to do all this? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - I do hate to be the bearer of bad news `:p`

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do sounds dangerous, as it could hit some false-positives, and change things unintentionally. Suppose your old domain is 'acme.de' and the new one 'acme.com', and some random visitor posted the following (this is an over-simplified example):

> I enjoy working with Acme.Depending on my mood.

It would be very easy to convert this to:

> I enjoy working with Acme.compending on my mood.

Therefore, my suggestions, in order of preference:

1. Don't update the DB at all, just configure your web server to redirect the .de traffic to the .com traffic. You're less likely to make mistakes this way.
2. If you must update the discussion board, do it in your display logic, rather than in the database--then you'll have no chance of making irrevocable mistakes.
3. Write a script in perl, or your favorite text-processing language, language, which does a regex replacement on every table/field.  I suggest the following strategy:

   a. Do a `SELECT id,<field name> FROM <table> WHERE <field name> LIKE '%domain.de%'`

   b. Store output in a CSV, or other format that is easy to parse.

   c. Run your Regex script to change **domain.de** to **domain.com**

   d. Check the output.

   e. Do an `UPDATE <table> SET <field>=? WHERE id=?`, with the output of your script.

   Do it in small chunks at first (a few tens or hundreds of posts at a time), and visually check the results before committing your changes to the database, to make sure you haven't made mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether this might work for you but have a look at this

The following query would give you the list of tables (120 tables)

```
   SELECT DISTINCT table_name
   FROM
   (
     SELECT *
     FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C
   ) t1
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='schema_name'
```

next
 you can use UPDATE query for each table. you can achieve this using [CURSORS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html)

I am not good in cursors but I think it will help in this situation